# How do I retrieve the zero-based index of the selected option in a select box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I have the following in my HTML code:

```
  <select name="Currency" id="Currency">
    <option value="0.85">Euro</option>
    <option value="110.33">Japanese Yen</option>
    <option value="1.2">Canadian Dollars</option>
  </select>
```

Using jQuery, I can use `$("#Currency").val()` to give me the selectd value, and I can use `$("#Currency :selected").text()` to get the selected text.

What do I need to do to get the zero-based index (in this case, 0, 1, or 2) of the current selection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the `selectedIndex` attribute:

```
var index = $("#Currency").attr("selectedIndex");
```

Check an example [here](http://jsbin.com/ohopo3).

Answer (score 1):

`$("Currency").attr("selectedIndex")`

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("Currency").selectedIndex;
```

Answer (score 0):

alternative method is to access the native javascript property.

```
$("#Currency")[0].selectedIndex
```